# Javascript: Using RegEx to read package in android manifest file

Tags: javascript

The manifest files are usually of android apk :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.myapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
```

I need to read the content between the quotes (e.g. `"com.example.myapp"`) of package and store it in a variable. I am using file reader to read the content of the file but my RegEx is weak, can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have supposedly stored the file in the variable filecontent, you can try out the following Regex -

```
packageId = fileContent.match(/package="(.*?)"/i)[1];
```

Here, We look for the first occurance of the word package in the file and extract the content from it so your packageId will be equal to "com.example.myapp".

Hope this helps !